# If a derived class object calls a base class function, static variable of which class will be modified?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, static

I have static variables in my base class. I want to create multiple derived classes from this base class but since static variables will be shared, I will have to duplicate them in each derived class. Now my question is, if a derived class object is calling a base class function which manipulates a static variable with same name, which copy will get modified - the one in base class or one in derived class?

```
class base 
{
  private:
    static int a;
  public:
     static void setvar (int x) {
         a = x;
     }
     static void printvar () {
         cout << a << endl;
     }
}

class derived1 : public base
{
   private:
     static int a;

}
class derived2 : public base
{
   private:
     static int a;

}

int main(void) {
   derived1 d1;
   derived2 d2;

   d1.setvar(5);
   d2.setvar(7);

   d1.printvar();
   d2.printvar();

 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you acutally want to achieve? Why is `setAndprint` non-static? Why do base and derived need an `a` and why does it have to be the same name in base and derived?

Comment: "but since static variables will be shared, I will have to duplicate them in each derived class. " why do you think you need to duplicate them?

Comment: setAndprint is also supposed to be static. thats a typo. I need static variables in my derived class. If I keep them only in base class, they will be shared across all classes which I dont want as I want each derived class static vars to be independent. I might be missing something but is there any other way to achieve what i want?

Comment: If I keep static vars only in derived class, base class functions will not have any knowledge of them and cant manipulate them.

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question is, if a derived class object is calling a base class function which manipulates a static variable with same name, which copy will get modified - the one in base class or one in derived class?

The `static` member variable will be modified.

If the intention is to update the derived class members, this is what I suggest.

1. Remove the member from the base class.
2. Add a `virtual` member function that will upate the variable.
3. Implement the `virtual` member function for each derived class and update the member variable corresponding to the derived class in the function.

```
class base 
{
  private:

    // Remove from base class.
    // static int a;

  public:
     virtual void setvar (int x) = 0; 
     virtual int getvar() const = 0;

     // This can't be static now.
     // static
     void printvar () const {
         cout << getvar() << endl;
     }
};

class derived1 : public base
{
   private:
     static int a;
     virtual void setvar (int x) { a = x; } 
     virtual int getvar() const { return a; }
};
```

Comment: lets assume setvar and getvar are very long functions. I will need to repeat them in each derived class?

Comment: @dgarg, No. You'll have to make sure that the derived class independent logic is coded in the base class and derived class specific logic is coded in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `a` in the base class is going to be set to 5. In order to make it easy to understand, just think about those `a`-s as completely different and totally unrelated variables, because they actually are.

Comment: Is there a way to have setAndprint to manipulate the derived class static variable?

Comment: @dgarg - no, not directly. Nothing prevents you from declaring a virtual function in the base class, overriding it in the derived class, doing your manipulations there, and calling it from the base class, but let me ask you, what in the world are you trying to achieve here in the first place???

Comment: Modified the code example to be more explicit on what I am trying to achieve. My goal is to "reuse" the functions setvar and printvar. At the same time i want to keep independent copies of  variable a in both derived classes.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make much sense to me. Why not just have `a` declared as non-static protected base member, initialized to different values in the derived classes as you see fit?

Comment: for some reasons (legacy code), i want 'a' to be static, at least for derived classes.

Comment: Well, as long as the actual setter doesn't have to be static, add some protected `int* pointerToTheCorrectStaticToAccess` to the base, init it to point to base `a` in the base ctor, change it to point to the derived `a`s in the derived ctors, and set via that pointer, in a base method, as a workaround. But really, your questions SCREAMS **there are likely some nasty design issues in there that are gonna bite you in the future**.

Comment: I feel like someone, a few years forward in this time line, wishing i'd STFU and not give you nasty ideas in that last comment, cause that someone now gotta clean the mess.

Comment: I agree about the design issues. I am not going to introduce them :) I think I have realized the problem. Thanks for your help in brainstorming.